# How to fill blank/empty cell in row using .writer in Python?

Tags: python, json, csv

My script ingests a real-time stream of high-frequency data.

Each row of data for a given timestamp has 7 possible parameters.

However, those 7 parameters may not come through on every single timestamp. For example:

```
timestamp 1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
1600      23   12   45   34   44   11   13
1601      23        45        34          
1602      23   12   45   55   34   11   12
1603      23   23   45   34   44   11     
1604                               11   13
```

The data reaches me as a JSON string which I parse and burn as CSV as follows:

```
            f = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'a', newline=''))
            f.writerow([
                x['data'][0]['timestamp'],
                x['data'][0]['param'][0]['1'],
                x['data'][0]['param'][0]['2'],
                x['data'][0]['param'][0]['3'],
                x['data'][0]['param'][0]['4'],
                x['data'][0]['param'][0]['5'],
                x['data'][0]['param'][0]['6'],
                x['data'][0]['param'][0]['7']
            ])
```

This will break because certain items will be blank in a given row.

What do you suggest that would allow me to burn a CSV as follows?

```
23,12,45,34,44,11,13
23,nan,45,nan,34,nan,nan
23,12,45,55,34,11,12
23,23,45,34,44,11,nan
nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,11,13
```

EDIT: typical incoming JSON (missing some keys/values)

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "s":"feed",
         "timestamp":1607300910205,
         "c":"sub",
         "param":[
            {
               "key":"CODE",
               "4":9,
               "5":11
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Perhaps prefill each row with NaN before ingesting the data for that timestamp?

Comment: it's a live data stream that feeds each row as a separate JSON string, how would one proceed to fill the missing keys/values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get) to replace the missing values with `'nan'` (or whatever default value you require):

```
f = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'a', newline=''))
f.writerow([
    x['data'][0]['timestamp'],
    x['data'][0]['param'][0].get('1', 'nan'),
    x['data'][0]['param'][0].get('2', 'nan'),
    x['data'][0]['param'][0].get('3', 'nan'),
    x['data'][0]['param'][0].get('4', 'nan'),
    x['data'][0]['param'][0].get('5', 'nan'),
    x['data'][0]['param'][0].get('6', 'nan'),
    x['data'][0]['param'][0].get('7', 'nan')
])
```

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks! (I was trying `.get` in perhaps the most asinine way, much appreciated)

Answer (score -1):

If you can assign the values that you want to be shown as nan to `np.nan`, the following solution should work:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4).astype(float)
arr[1, 1] = arr[2, 3] = np.nan

print(arr)
# [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
# [ 4. nan  6.  7.]
# [ 8.  9. 10. nan]]

np.savetxt("out.csv", arr, delimiter=",", fmt="%.0f")

# out.csv content:
# 0,1,2,3
# 4,nan,6,7
# 8,9,10,nan
```

Notice the example uses a float array, then saves the CSV file with `%.0f` format to print the data like integer. This is because only float arrays can have nan values. So, make sure you convert your data to float array as in the example.

Comment: please see OP with Edit—the solution should address the incoming data structure as JSON

Comment: Well, the answer is supposed to give you an idea, not the exact solution of your particular work. That is why, completing the most trivial part, where the input JSON is organized as a numpy array is left to the developer.